# Getting the title attribute of an accordon panel before it opens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion that is created at run time from the results of a database query.

The accordion is functioning correctly, expanding and collapsing as it should.

I have loaded the panel header with the title attribute with the unique number from the database query.

```
<a id="panelHeader" class="accordion-toggle header-only" title="'+ _cardID +'" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#UnAssignedAccordion"
```

Now - i would like to execute a function right before the panel is expanded.

This is the route i was thinking about,

```
  $('#UnAssignedAccordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
//    var _cardID = parseInt($(this).attr('title'));
    var active = $(".selector").accordion("option", "active");
    alert(active);
  });
```

but i cannot seem to locate the title attribute.

I have looked through the e and the this...  but i have had no luck.

anyone have any ideas o could point me in the correct direction?

The question is : need to get the value of the title attrib from the panel that is about to be opened.

Comment: `$('#panelHeader').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {...});` Try it this time, this function returns what?

Comment: Without more details of your code it's difficult to understand what is going on. I can be much more helpful if you provide more code and a more detailed explanation.

That being said, have you tried looking in e.target?

Comment: Post the html structure

Comment: Need a working fiddle to debug.

Comment: @pithhelmet did you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried implementing the sample for the mentioned code and it works.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">link</a>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse" title="2">
        XYZ
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $('#demo').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        var _cardID =Number($(this).attr('title'));
        var active = $(".selector").accordion("option", "active");
        alert(active);
    });
</script>
```

Please try using the code and let us know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.

I took the code block from @patilprashant6792 and changed it a little bit.

Since the accordion is being built at run time, i did not know the the ID of the div yet, so i added a class to the div.  "content-area-div"

And i also had to move the code block from my global JS file, and place it into the code block where the looping occurs that fill in the accordion.

```
  $('.contents-area-div').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var _cardID = $(this).attr('title');
    var active = $(".selector").accordion("option", "active");

    loadPanelContents(_cardID);

  });
```

Here is the panel line

```
<div id="cardID' + _cardID + '" title="' + _cardID +'" class="contents-area-div panel-collapse collapse">
```

Thanks again everyone!